# Run the same command multiple times in background

Tags: bash, command-line, background-process

How is it possible to run multiple commands and background them using bash?

For example:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do wait file$i &; done
```

where wait is a custom binary.

Right now I get an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

when running the above command.

Once backgrounded the commands should run in parallel.

Comment: Am ashuming your not referring to: `nohup` allowing you to execute a command in the background

Comment: The error you're seeing is due to `&` and `;` are both "command terminators". You don't need to use both: `for ...; do wait $arg & done` will work.

Comment: @glenn jackman. Yes, I actually tried it after posting the question. There is no need for both ; and &

Comment: For future readers, [a link to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists): "A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by **one** of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline." (emphasis mine)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14753491/560648

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `&`, just like `;` is a [list terminator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222) operator. They have the same syntax and can be used interchangeably (depending on what you want to do). This means that you don't want, or need, `command1 &; command2`, all you need is `command1 & command2`.

So, in your example, you could just write:

```
for i in {1..10}; do wait file$i & done
```

and each `wait` command will be launched in the background and the loop will immediately move on to the next.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of compatibility use the posix form instead of expansion:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do (./wait file$i &); done
```

Comment: Note that `seq` is not a POSIX command and is generally only found on GNU systems. The behaviour or `$(...)` (and `$i`) depends on the current value of `$IFS`. Also note that by doing `(cmd &)`, `cmd` will be a child of a subshell, so you won't be able to wait for and get its exit status for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can group the commands and put the grouped commands in background. Like :

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do ((wait file$i)&); done
```

Comment: There is no need to use the inner parentheses...

Comment: only need to use the inner parentheses if you want to put in the background multiple commands as asked in the question. Like ((sleep 1; wait file$i)&);

Answer (score 2):

Is your binary really named `wait`? I don't recommend to do so, because `wait` is a shell builtin.

I believe bash doesn't parse well a one-line loop that launches background processes. I suggest you to change the code to:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do ./wait file$i & echo "Running 'wait' using PID=$!..."; done
```